# How to end game in hangman if ALL letters in the secret word are in guessed_letters list

Tags: python, for-loop

Im trying to create a for loop end game by doing for "every letter in my secret word if All letters are in gussed_letters then end game."

Ive tried to make a correct_letters list and see if all the letters in my secret word are in my correct_letters list then end the game but i cant seem to get it to work.

```
import random



words = ['apple',' python','parent'] #Make list of words
def randomword(words): #takes in list words
  return random.choice(words) #returns a random element back
chosenword = randomword(words) # make a variable equal to the function


#variables (tries you get and list to letters gussed. )
tries = 10
guess_letters = []

def dashshow(guess_letters): #takes in guess_letters
  for letter in chosenword: #checks each letter in chosenword
    if letter in guess_letters: #if letter in guess_letters print that letter
      print(letter)
    else: #or else print a dash
      print('-')



def playgame(tries):# Takes tries
  while  tries != 0: #While tries is not 0
    guess = str(input("Guess a letter of the word: ")).lower() #Ask for a guess
    guess_letters.append(guess) #add guess to guess_letters list
    if guess in chosenword: #if your guess in chosenword 
      print("You got a letter correct!") 
      tries -= 1
    elif guess not in chosenword: 
      print("That letter is not in the word")
      tries -= 1
    dashshow(guess_letters) # last call the dashshow function


randomword(words)
playgame(tries)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the dashshow function count how many dashes left and return a value for whether any are left. If not, the game is over and has been won.

```
import random



words = ['apple',' python','parent'] #Make list of words
def randomword(words): #takes in list words
  return random.choice(words) #returns a random element back
chosenword = randomword(words) # make a variable equal to the function


#variables (tries you get and list to letters gussed. )
tries = 10
guess_letters = []

def dashshow(guess_letters): #takes in guess_letters
  dashes = 0
  for letter in chosenword: #checks each letter in chosenword
    if letter in guess_letters: #if letter in guess_letters print that letter
      print(letter)
    else: #or else print a dash
      print('-')
      dashes = dashes+1
  return(dashes>0)    



def playgame(tries):# Takes tries
  keepPlaying = True
  while  (tries != 0) and keepPlaying: #While tries is not 0
    guess = str(input("Guess a letter of the word: ")).lower() #Ask for a guess
    guess_letters.append(guess) #add guess to guess_letters list
    if guess in chosenword: #if your guess in chosenword 
      print("You got a letter correct!") 
      tries -= 1
    elif guess not in chosenword: 
      print("That letter is not in the word")
      tries -= 1
    if not dashshow(guess_letters): # last call the dashshow function
      keepPlaying=False
      print("you win!")


randomword(words)
playgame(tries)
```

Comment: where I have dashes=dashes+1 you could say dashes += 1. Or you could start with result=False and where I say dashes+=1 say result = True, and then return result. But the key idea is to see if you have any dashes left while you are writing them.

Comment: Also, what does the parenthesis  after the return mean? if dashes is greater than 0 then return?

Comment: it returns true or false as the result of the function. If dashes>0, it returns true, that we should keep playing. If dashes is not greater than 0, it returns false, which means the game is done. That returned value is then reacted to by the code that called the function.

Answer (score 0):

you can create variable is list letters of secret word, remove letter if it similars guess

Try this

```py
def playgame(tries):# Takes tries
  chosenword_ = list(chosenword)
  while  tries != 0 and chosenword_: #While tries is not 0
    guess = str(input("Guess a letter of the word: ")).lower() #Ask for a guess
    guess_letters.append(guess) #add guess to guess_letters list
    if guess in chosenword: #if your guess in chosenword 
      print("You got a letter correct!") 
      tries -= 1
      try: 
        chosenword_.remove(guess)
      except ValueError:
        pass
    elif guess not in chosenword: 
      print("That letter is not in the word")
      tries -= 1
    dashshow(guess_letters) # last call the dashshow function
```